# Asymptotic behavior of $\frac{\Gamma \left(2-\frac{1}{p}\right) \Gamma (t+1)}{\Gamma \left(t-\frac{1}{p}+2\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function

I'm looking to find $t$ that satisfies the following equation, and treat it as $g(p)$, a function of $p>1$

$$
\frac{\Gamma \left(2-\frac{1}{p}\right) \Gamma (t+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(t-\frac{1}{p}+2\right)}=0.01
$$

Empirically, it seems like the following expression is an upper bound on $\log_{10} g$
$$5(p-1)^\frac{3}{4}$$

[image]
[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-inverse-gamma.nb)

1. Is this correct/tight upper bound?
2. What is the asymptotic behavior of $g(p)$ as $p\to 1$?
3. What is asymptotic behavior of $g(p)$ as $p\to\infty$?

Comment: Maybe find a series expansion and truncate?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your graph.  What's your value of $g(3)$?

Comment: `g(3)=856.89`, Note that graph shows $\log_{10}(g)$, updated axis label to avoid confusion. Some other sample values are in [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-inverse-gamma.nb)

Comment: Anyway, I don't think your expression $\frac{5}{(p-1)^{3/4}}$ can be correct, because it seems to me $g(p)$ is always going to be above $100$, no?

Comment: @BrianTung interesting...yes, it does seem like g(p) tends to $1/\epsilon$ as $p\to\infty$

Comment: Asymptotically, I make it $g(p) \sim 100\left(1+\frac{\ln 100 - 1 + \gamma}{p-1}\right)$.  This is a very loose approximation for small $p$.  For example, as you point out, $g(3) \approx 856.89$, but the above expression gives $g(3) \approx 351$ or so.

Comment: Maybe it will always be above $99$?  I might be off by $1$...

Comment: @BrianTung also, I'm getting $g(1.01)\approx 10^{201.75}$ while your version gives me $46109.3$

Comment: @BrianTung trying $g(10^6)$, I'm getting `99.00041`, so probably 99 is right

Comment: Yes.  As I said, the approximation is very loose when $p$ is small (say, less than $10$ or $20$?).  It gets better as $p \to \infty$.  I haven't worked out a good approximation for $p$ close to $1$ (and as I say, I might have gotten off by $1$ on the one I gave--a common hazzard with the gamma function!).

Comment: Yup, I missed a $-1$, so it should be $g(p) \sim 100\left(1+\frac{\ln 100-1+\gamma}{p}\right)-1$ as $p \to \infty$ (because of course $\frac{1}{p-1} \sim \frac1p$).  I'll think about $p \to 1$.

Comment: Yes, as $p \to 1$, let $N = \frac{p}{p-1}$, and then $g(p) \sim 100^Ne^{-\gamma}$.  For instance, with $p = 1.01$, we have $N = 101$, and then $g(1.01) \approx 100^{101}e^{-\gamma} \approx 10^{201.75}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of a few asymptotic expressions for the gamma function as $p \to \infty$:

$$
\Gamma\left(2-\frac1p\right) \sim 1-\frac{1-\gamma}{p}
$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and

$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(t+2-\frac1p\right)}{\Gamma(t+1)} \sim (t+1)^{1-\frac1p}
$$

Then we have

$$
\frac{1-\frac{1-\gamma}{p}}{(t+1)^{1-\frac1p}} \approx \frac{1}{100}
$$

$$
(t+1)^{1-\frac1p} \approx 100\left(1-\frac{1-\gamma}{p}\right)
$$

\begin{align}
t+1 & \approx 100^\frac{p}{p-1} \left(1-\frac{1-\gamma}{p-1}\right) \\
    & \approx 100 \left(1+\frac{\ln 100}{p-1}\right)
                \left(1-\frac{1-\gamma}{p-1}\right) \\
    & \approx 100 \left(1+\frac{\ln 100-1+\gamma}{p-1}\right) \\
    & \approx 100 \left(1+\frac{\ln 100-1+\gamma}{p}\right)
\end{align}

since $\frac{1}{p-1} \sim \frac{1}{p}$, and finally we get

$$
t \approx 100 \left(1+\frac{\ln 100-1+\gamma}{p}\right) - 1
$$

---

Similarly, as $p \to 1$, we let $N = \frac{p}{p-1}$, and then as $N \to \infty$, we have

$$
\Gamma\left(1+\frac1N\right) \sim 1-\frac{\gamma}{N}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(t+1+\frac1N\right)}{\Gamma(t+1)} \sim \sqrt[N]{t}
$$

Then we can have

$$
\frac{1-\frac{\gamma}{N}}{\sqrt[N]{t}} \approx \frac{1}{100}
$$

$$
\sqrt[N]{t} \approx 100\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{N}\right)
$$

$$
t \approx 100^N e^{-\gamma}
$$

---

It should be clear how to generalize this for ratios other than $\frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: I'm using this in a write-up for average case analysis of gradient descent, if you email me at yaroslavvb@gmail.com, I'll cite you properly

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: The above isn't written anywhere near rigorously.  If this is for a blog post, no problem, but if you're writing a paper, it would need to be tightened up.